# How do I rewrite this with 'recompose'?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I have this class component and want to rewrite it to stateless functional component with `recompose`:

```
export default class Popular extends Component {
    state = {
        value: 0,
        selected: "All",
        repos: null
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.handleSelected(this.state.selected)
}

handleChange = (e, value) => {
    this.setState({ value })
}

handleSelected = lang => {
    this.setState({
        selected: lang,
        repos: null
    })
    fetchPopularRepos(lang).then(repos => {
        this.setState({
            selected: lang,
            repos
        })
    })
}
```

I'm struggling to combine `onSelectLanguage` and `onFetchRepos` in one function as in my code before refactoring. I don't know how to rewrite this for my componentDidMount function as well.

### UPDATE:

got this working with:

```
const enhance = compose(
  withStateHandlers(initialState, {
    onChangeLanguage,
    onSelectLanguage
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      fetchPopularRepos(this.props.selected).then(repos => {
        this.setState({
          repos
        })
      })
    }
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.selected !== prevProps.selected) {
        this.setState({ repos: null })
        fetchPopularRepos(this.props.selected).then(repos => {
          this.setState({
            repos
          })
        })
      }
    }
  })
)
```

These lifecycles don't look very sexy though. Not sure if this worth refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending on the previous answer, you could use functional composition to combine the `onFetchRepos` and `onSelectLanguage` as required. 
If I understand your requirements correctly, you should be able to achieve this by the following:

```
const initialState = {
    value: 0,
    selected: "All",
    repos: null
}

const onChangeLanguage = props => (event, value) => ({
    value
})

const onSelectLanguage = props => lang => ({
    selected: lang
})

const onFetchRepos = props => (fetchPopularRepos(props.selected).then(repos => ({
    repos
})))

// Combined function: onFetchRepos followed by call to onSelectLanguage
const onFetchReposWithSelectLanguage = props => onFetchRepos(props)
      .then(response => props.onSelectLanguage(response))

// Minimal code to compose a functional component with both state handers and 
// lifecycle handlers
const enhance = compose(
    withStateHandlers(initialState, {
        onChangeLanguage,
        onSelectLanguage
    }),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            // Fetch repos and select lang on mount
            onFetchReposWithSelectLanguage(this.props)
        }
    })
)
```

#### Update

```
// Minimal code to compose a functional component with both state handers and 
// lifecycle handlers
const enhance = compose(
    withStateHandlers(initialState, {
        onChangeLanguage,
        onSelectLanguage,
        setRepos
    }),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            // Reuse onSelectLanguage logic and call setState manually, use setState callback that
            // fires after state is updated to trigger fetch based on newState.selected language
            this.setState(onSelectLanguage(this.props.selected)(this.props), newState => {
                fetchPopularRepos(newState.selected).then(repos => {
                    this.setState({
                        repos
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })
)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I get this error `onFetchRepos(...).then is not a function`. Anyway, I don't think this is what I want. If you look to my initial code (not refactored), the `handleSelected` takes a `lang` argument and then it sets that lang to `selected` then that `lang` argument is taken by `fetchPopularRepos` which returns `repos` and sets it to the state. Furthermore `handleSelected` is a method that is passed to children component (menu), where I can select `lang` and fetch new `repos` again. That part is not shown in my code.

Comment: I noticed a typo in `onFetchRepos()` - there was a redundant `() =>`. See my latest edit

Comment: I don't want to pass response which is repos to `props.onSelectLanguage(response)`. It should be vice versa. I want to pass `lang` argument and then i get that language on my state as `selected` and then it fetches `repos` of that lang and set array of repos to `repos` on the state if thats make sense

Comment: I want to pass initial `lang` which is `All` when componentDidMount, but after that I want to pass any `lang` to `onFetchReposWithSelectLanguage`

Comment: If you want to express this by a single composed function, it seems to me you will need access to `setState` in order to trigger re-rendering after data has been fetched. I'll add an update to the answer - hopefully that can help you :-)

Comment: I very appreciate your help

Comment: Ok great! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case where you'd want to use [the `lifecycle()` method](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle). I'm not a `recompose` expert, however I think the following adjustments might achieve what you're after:

```
const onFetchPopularRepos = props => () => {
    // Make sure the method returns the promise
    return fetchPopularRepos(props.selected).then(repos => ({  
        repos: repos
    }))
}

const withPopularReposState = withStateHandlers(initialState, {
    onChangeLanguage,
    onSelectLanguage
})

// Add a life cycle hook to fetch data on mount
const withLifecycle = lifecycle({
  componentDidMount() {

    // Update the state
    onFetchPopularRepos(this.props).then(newState => this.setState(newState)) 
  }
})();

// Compose the functional component with both lifecycle HOC
const enhance = withLifecycle(withPopularReposState)
```

Comment: how do I combine `onSelectLanguage` and `onFetchRepos` in one function so I can call these functions together?

Comment: Hi @karolis2017 , I've provided a second answer below - does this help you?